# Internet explorer 11 "Not enough storage" error

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

When I try to get an ajax response around 100 mb I get this error:

Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 8007000e.
“Not enough storage is available to complete this operation”

I don't get such errors with other browsers.

Why does it happen ?

I use IE 11. Windows 8.1 64bit 16GB RAM

[image]

Comment: A 100 MB Ajax response? O_o What are you doing with the data?

Comment: yes it's my business requirement.

Comment: But what are you doing with the data?

Comment: It's an intranet application, I'm trying to load some huge map data and trying to cluster it on client side.

Comment: @NLV There is no solution. It's a memory fragmentation issue of the 32 bit IE process. You need to reduce the size of the responses. Eric's answer here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a9c94529-9c63-484d-acc6-457641a8f18c/internet-explorer-11-not-enough-storage-error?forum=iewebdevelopment

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem with one of applications. The same stuff worked well in Firefox and Chrome. In my case IE failed when it consumed more than 1.2 GB memory. I also noticed memory management was better in Firefox and Chrome and it stayed less than 800M all the time.

If you have a similar situation you can capture memory footprints from IE and other Browser using developer tools to get further clue. In my case problem was due to a third party component application used.

Comment: I have experienced this on opening many tabs of my app. On 11th tab memory go over 1.2GB, and IE fails.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've reached the quota for your local browser storage. Here's a link you can refer to see the various storage limitations of each browser.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/

If pulling the request.reponseText doesn't throw the error itself (without the JSON.parse-ing), try to consider storing it in an  IndexedDB. As per the link above, IE11 can hold from 100MB of data

Steps on how to create one can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj154905(v=vs.85).aspx

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/

Comment: The problem is not about JSON.parse-ing. I get the same error without it. The error is thrown at request.reponseText.