# What is the meaning of Ajax Status 8 in IE?

Tags: ajax, debugging, internet-explorer

In our web application accessed via IE11, sometimes we see a strange response for some Ajax Requests and the code/status is 0x8 highlighted in red color in the "Developer Tools" (F12 Network Requests) of IE Browser.

[image]

[image]

In the console we can see this message:

[image]

What is the potential cause for this and how to troubleshoot further?

Comment: You will see error message in details of the call. It is on the lines of 'Not enough storage space' which means the registry is full on either the server or the client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet explorer 11 "Not enough storage" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405826/internet-explorer-11-not-enough-storage-error)

Comment: Do you mean the Windows Registry? Subsequent requests are working as well.